# JWPlayer = youtube videos not playing on JWPlayer insted playing youtube version

Tags: jwplayer, jwplayer6, jwplayer7

I have noticed that one of our machines is not playing youtube videos on JWplayer code instead it is playing on default youtube code. But most of the machines works as expected.

Please see attached image and I would appreciate your quick help on this.
[Image-screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swf2Q.png)

Comment: Which image? There is none?

Comment: I have added the image now

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are directly using the YouTube embed code. JW Player uses the official iFrame player API from YouTube to play a video inside of JW Player, so you will need to embed JW Player and add the YouTube video as the source. More info can be found on the JW Player Support site: https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1406725-youtube-video-embed